# Extracting Time from Timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Redshift and am looking to extract the time from the timestamp.

Here is the timestamp: 2017-10-31 23:30:00

and I would just like to get the time as 23:30:00

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Redshift you can simply cast the value to a `time`:

```
the_timestamp_column::time
```

alternatively you can use the standard `cast()` [operator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CAST_function.html):

```
cast(the_timestamp_column as time)
```

Comment: tested as working using select '2017-10-31 23:30:00'::timestamp::time; returns 23:30:00

Comment: Would we be able to use this method on an entire column? When I try it, I get this error message: `Function ""time"(timestamp without time zone)" not supported.` Would I have to specify a timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Please go through this link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html

> timezone, timezone_hour, timezone_minute
>
> Supported by the DATE_TRUNC function and the EXTRACT for time stamp
>   with time zone (TIMESTAMPTZ)

Examples is here

```
select extract(minute from timestamp '2009-09-09 12:08:43');
select extract(hours from timestamp '2009-09-09 12:08:43');
```

Comment: This answer does not return 23:30:00 using "2017-10-31 23:30:00" as input

Comment: Try select substring(convert(varchar(150),'2016-01-04 00:12:06'),12,8)

Comment: right but - see the correct answer above which is simply "::time"