# Amazon redshift - extracting time from timestamp SQL error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract the time from a datetime column in my Amazon Redshift database (Postgresql 8.0). I have already referred to previous questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069483/extracting-time-from-timestamp-in-sql). But I am getting an unusual error.

When I try:

```
SELECT collected_timestamp::time
```

or

```
SELECT cast(collected_timestamp as time)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables
```

The goal is to pull the time portion from the timestamp such that `2017-11-06 13:03:28` returns `13:03:28`.

This seems like an easy problem to solve but for some reason I am missing something. Researching that error does not lead to anything meaningful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that **Redshift <> PostgreSQL** - it was forked from PostgreSQL but is very different under the hood.

You're trying to cast a timestamp value to a data type of "time" which does not exist in Redshift. To return a value that is only the time component of a timestamp you will need to cast it to a character data type, e.g.:

```
SELECT to_char(collected_timestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: not quite right yet but good direction - need to cast the result back to a time?

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no such data type as TIME in Redshift, so it is not possible to cast anything to "a time".

Comment: interesting - i hadn't spotted that - although my sql below (that casts to ::time)  does run without error AND you can actually perform calculations on that as a TIME!. But you cannot create a table with a time format.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways, here is one i use:

```
SELECT ('2018-03-07 21:55:12'::timestamp - trunc('2018-03-07 21:55:12'::timestamp))::time;
```

I hope that helps.

EDIT: I have made incorrect use of ::time please see comments on other answer.

Comment: unfortunately, this still throws the same error mentioned above

Comment: please share how you implemented my code? if you just copy paste that line of code it does work right?

Comment: Yes, if I copy and paste your code it works. But it does not work when I use my table. It seems to be an Amazon Redshift issue and not a syntax issue.

Comment: I was just hoping to see if there was a hack to get around it

Comment: I have asked you to share your implementation so that I can help you fix it!