# Join tables with different datetime formats

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join

I have two tables with different columns representing time.

**Table 1** contains coordinates for every second from one particular day (March 20, 2022):

| time | Coordinates |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-20T09:16:23.000 | x/y |
| 2022-03-20T09:16:25.000 | x/y |
| 2022-03-20T09:16:27.000 | x/y |

**Table 2** contains number of registered events by time (also from March 20, but we have just time without date and milliseconds):

| time | Number of events |
| --- | --- |
| 09:16:23 | 23 |
| 09:16:27 | 53 |

I want to join this tables to extract column with coordinates and additional columns for every row from the Table 2. **Desired result**:

| time | Coordinates | Number of events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 09:16:23 | x/y | 23 |
| 09:16:27 | x/y | 53 |

How I can do it by using **Python** or **SQL**?

Comment: what is the type of "time" in your data? (string? datetime?)

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069483/extracting-time-from-timestamp-in-sql
to see how to do it in SQL

Answer (score 0):

With pandas you can ensure both time are in a common format (datetime, string) and `merge`:

```
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time']).dt.time

# only if df2['time'] are strings
#df2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['time']).dt.time

df1.merge(df2, on='time')
```

output:

```
       time Coordinates  Number of events
0  09:16:23         x/y                23
1  09:16:27         x/y                53
```

if you rather prefer to use strings, you can convert the time in df1 with: `pd.to_datetime(df1['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Thank you!
But for both of these commands I have the same error:

TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime.

The type of "time" column from df1 is - datetime64[ns, SimpleTZ("Z")].
Type from df2 - object.

Comment: If you already have the correct type in df2, don't convert ;)